# Extern syntax in C?

Tags: c, extern, gameboy

I am slightly confused about using "extern" in my c code, when there is a global variable involved. 
I tried the following, and got a compilation error:

Main.c:

```
extern unsigned short *videobuffer;
//I also tried this in a separate and it failed with the same compilation error//
extern (unsigned short *)videobuffer;
```

lib.c:

```
unsigned short *videobuffer = (unsigned short *)0x6000000;
```

The error I received:

```
[COMPILE] Compiling main.c
main.c:16: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'unsigned'
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: How do you compile and link these two sources? You can *compile* but not *link* just your `main.c`. (And better don't try random stuff such as throwing in parentheses "until it works". You can easily look up the correct syntax elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

Valid code is usually what people want here:

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern unsigned short *videobuffer;

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", videobuffer);
}
```

#### lib.c

```
unsigned short *videobuffer = (unsigned short *)0x6000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

the following is correct:

Main.c:

```
extern unsigned short *videobuffer;
```

lib.c:

```
unsigned short *videobuffer = (unsigned short *)0x6000000;
```

The `extern` keyword tells the compiler there is a variable, but it is not in this compilation unit.

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting the same error in compilation as stated above.

Comment: Then you declare it at the wrong place. It must be before any statement and would best be declared before any function, after all includes. There can also be a syntax error before the declaration, which only triggers a compiler error later. Please show us more code.